# How to detect tap on clear part of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have view controller with UITableView. Height of table view is static and == height of screen. Number of rows in table can change and sometimes it might be a situation when number of rows is less than number of rows which can be visible, so appears some clear area on bottom of table. Can i detect tap on it without gesture recognizer? Are there some delegate methods of UITableView?

Comment: To selected use didSelectRowAtIndexPath, or you can use tapgesture also.

Comment: @VictorIppolitov what about creating a UITableView sub class, assign that to your table view, and overriding touchesBegan on the new sub class?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, there are delegate methods, such as:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However, this will only tell you if a tap occurs on an existing row. If you want to capture taps on the empty space below the rows (or on a section header) you will need to use a gesture recognizer. You can do something like this:

```
// in viewDidLoad or somewhere similar
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableTapped:)];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
//.........

- (void)tableTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    CGPoint location = [tap locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    if(path)
    {
        // tap was on existing row, so pass it to the delegate method
        [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
    }
    else
    {
        // handle tap on empty space below existing rows however you want
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: for an alternative approach, consider [Connor Neville's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41555961/2788608) from his answer on this post and add the gesture recognizer to the table's background.

Comment: You're wanting to grab a gesture on an area that doesn't automatically grab gestures via the delegate, so AFAIK there's no easy way around a gesture recognizer.

Comment: Now a cant handle event "tableTapped". I added UIGestureRecognizerDelegate but it don't work.

Comment: @VictorIppolitov you may need to change the variable name from `self.tableView` to whatever the instance/class variable name is for your table.

Comment: @VictorIppolitov I assume you've probably found the solution to that problem in the last 5 months, but just in case (or if anyone else has the same question) you need to create a gesture recognizer for each view. You can't reuse the same recognizer on multiple views (which is why it only worked on the last one). They can share a target method, but they need to be unique gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 61):

All of the supplied answers, including the accepted answer, add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `tableView`; while this will work, I've found that this gesture recognizer can interfere with row taps and triggering `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in a somewhat unpredictable/nondeterministic way.

If you want to detect taps in the "blank space" **as well as in rows**, I highly suggest adding a **background view** to your table, and add the gesture recognizer there:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableTapped))
self.tableView.backgroundView = UIView()
self.tableView.backgroundView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: **This is the best answer**: it preserves also the `tableView` selection responder so you can see also the selection of your rows.

Comment: If you can't get this to work and you're using something like an empty dataset, check to see if the backgroundView isn't changed in another part of your code!

Comment: To get this to work you need to add `tableView.backgroundView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: @FemiLoki `isUserInteractionEnabled` defaults to true: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-isuserinteractionenabled

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to @Stonz2, swift version:

**Swift 4**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableTapped))
self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc func tableTapped(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = tap.location(in: self.tableView)
    let path = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    if let indexPathForRow = path {
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPathForRow)
    } else {
        // handle tap on empty space below existing rows however you want
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableTapped))
self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func tableTapped(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = tap.location(in: self.tableView)
    let path = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    if let indexPathForRow = path {
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPathForRow)
    } else {
        // handle tap on empty space below existing rows however you want
    }
}
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableTapped))
self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


func tableTapped(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = tap.locationInView(self.tableView)
    let path = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location)
    if let indexPathForRow = path {
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPathForRow)
    } else {
        // handle tap on empty space below existing rows however you want
    }
}
```

Comment: UITableViewCell's `setSelected()` won't get called if you call only `didSelectRowAt()`. So I added self.tableView.selectRow(at:) before `didSelectRowAt()` and then `setSelected()` worked properly.

Answer (score -4):

You don't need gesture recogniser. You should impliment `<UITableViewDelegate>` in your `ViewController.h` and then add this method to your `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

where `indexPath` is index of clicked row/column.

Comment: This will not supply any information about taps on the `tableView` that are in the empty space below existing rows, which is what the asker is asking about.