# Limit the cell selection area in uitable view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell in table view, which allows multiple selection. Can i limit the cell selection area of a custom cell. Can i enable selection area to only the left side of the cell not the entire cell.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: you can use UITapGestureRecognizer for it

Comment: Check this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141254/how-to-detect-tap-on-clear-part-of-uitableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141254/how-to-detect-tap-on-clear-part-of-uitableview) OR [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070874/how-can-i-distinguish-which-part-of-uitableviewcell-has-been-clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070874/how-can-i-distinguish-which-part-of-uitableviewcell-has-been-clicked)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I shall add UITapGestureRecognizer to the right side of the cell? i have a text field on the cell

Comment: You can add a button on cell too whatever size you want. And then use that button for selection

Comment: You could add UIView with clear color to hold view and put it above all subViews, this could be simple fix.

Comment: @ZaidPathan  i have a text field on the cell custom cell. Shall i add UIView to the cell except text field area?

Comment: if you want half textfield clickable then add it below textfield, otherwise above it.

Answer (score 3):

In your `UITableViewCell` subclass override `pointInside:withEvent:` method and return `YES` only for the points inside the area you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the way you want can be implemented, You make a button on left side of your cell. So Whenever you click on button your selected are will be enabled.

You do not need to implement any logic in UITableView DidSelectRowForIndexPath.
Need to manage in your button.

Comment: I have been doing that, its creating a lot of mess, to get the button selection and maintaining a selection duplicate array.

Comment: Yes, It need to maintain the array, but in further processing it will be helpful. I also used this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `UIButton` on the left side of your cell, by this way you can easily handle the selection of `UIButton` by using its `tag` value.

Comment: The problems are more if I implement in this way. you have to maintain button selection for visible and nonvisible rows.

Comment: I think its not big deal if you are using model class and Using array to fill up data in each cell.

Comment: You can also add a UIView on cell and make its user interaction disabled. I think it will be better. Try it.

Comment: @Sunny, I tried - UIView alone doesn't make any effect (disregarding of interaction enabled or disabled, the cell is selected).
With UIButton is better, but user interaction must be *enabled*, otherwise, again, cell is selected.

Answer (score 0):

In the custom tableView Cell. The are which you want to be non clickable add a button to that area and if a tap is registered in the button the `didselectitem` at indexPath would not be called I have done a similar implementation myself.

[My TableView Implementation](https://github.com/Ibrahimhass/tableViewWithMultipleCustomTableViewCells/upload/master)

Comment: As you are using Objective-C it is the exact out of the box solution for you

Comment: remove the extra tableView and tweak the code and you are good to go if you need any assiatance please comment down under here