# UIGestureRecognizer on background of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am currently creating a UITableView with custom cells to allow users to search other users. When the table is filled with data (usernames), it works great. I check if the keyboard is visible when a tap is detected, and if so, I dismiss the keyboard. If the keyboard is not shown, it pushes to the UIViewController containing the user's profile. This is the code to do so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if(keyboardShowing) {

        dismissKeyboard()
        return

    }

    let userVC = UserController()
    let navViewController = tabBarController?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
    userVC.profileUserID = resultUsers[indexPath.row].userID
    navViewController?.pushViewController(userVC, animated: true)

}
```

However, when there is only one row (so the search returns one user, for example), I want to be able to click outside the rows to allow the user to dismiss the keyboard. I tried the following:

```
let tableBGTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
self.userList.backgroundView?.addGestureRecognizer(tableBGTap)
```

This doesn't work though. Any idea on how I can make it possible to achieve what I want? Long story short: if there are fewer rows in my UITableView to fill the entire screen, I want to be able to tap on the "background" below the rows.

Comment: Although I already posted an answer, it's already mentioned in the duplicated question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41555961/5501940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of why

```
self.userList.backgroundView?.addGestureRecognizer(tableBGTap)
```

is not working because `backgroundView` is `nil`. Therefore, what you should do is:

```
userList.backgroundView = UIView()
self.userList.backgroundView?.addGestureRecognizer(tableBGTap)
```

---

**Note That** if you are setting a background color for the table view:

```
userList.backgroundColor = .red
```

won't be displayed anymore. As a workaround, you could add a color to the background view itself:

```
userList.backgroundView = UIView()
userList.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red
userList.backgroundView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapper)
```